# Decompose table into third normal form

Tags: database, normalization, functional-dependencies

Tables X and Y are given as below :

```
X (A, B, D, E, F, G, H, J) with A and B as primary key
Y (K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R) with K and L as primary key
```

Now we need to decompose these tables into tables in the third normal form using the functional dependencies specified below:

1. A   ->  G, H
2. B   ->  D, E, F
3. E   ->  F
4. H   ->  G
5. L   ->  N, O, P, Q
6. N   ->  Q

I need to specify primary keys and foreign keys also. Please help to solve this problem.

I came across this problem in a text book and let me make it very clear that its not any homework assignment. I am learning normalization. If I normalize to 2NF I loose some relations which doesn't suit to 3NF. So I am confused. Any help will be appreciated. Because to convert to 3NF I need to go through 2NF too.

I had converted to 3NF . But not sure if its right. Please help

```
R1 (E, F)
R2 (H, G)
R3 (A, B, J)
R4 (A, H)
R5 (B, D, E)

R6 (N, Q)
R7 (K, L, M, R)
R8 (L, N, O, P)
```

Now main problem am facing is in finding primary key and foreign key relations

Comment: How did you derive R3 and R7?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I had said that I may be wrong.As i am learning normalisation. Can you please help to correct it ?

Comment: How did you derive R3 and R7?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I edited R3 and R7. There were mistakes in it. Now can you please help to find foreign and primary keys ?

Comment: PKs & FKs are irrelevant to normalization to higher NFs. CKs matter. So find a definition of CK. Also in practice we do not normalize to a desired NF by going through lower NFs, we use a proven algorithm for the NF. What is your textbook name & edition? When you say "A and B" do you mean "(the set) {A, B}"? "I lose some relations which doesn't suit to 3NF" is not clear. Do you mean, you lose some FDs? Also, you need to explain how you got your answers--show your work.